# How to call REST Service from SQL function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, rest

I have a to create a job running in SQL Server, this should be calling sql function, and that function will have functionality to make a call to rest service to delete all records for the day.

Comment: What? If you're already on DB level, why call a REST service that calls back to the DB to remove the data (assuming that the REST service communicates with this very database)?!

Comment: You don't want to put http requests inside of a database.

Comment: why will you have to call rest from DB ? what is your requirement ?
One thing you can do :
In SQL Server Agent, create a job which calls a batch file. Configure the batch file which calls the rest service.
I can't think any other solution right now.

Comment: I have a rest service which already takes care of cleaning table various dependent databases., What I need is to just call the service and schedule a job. I want this to be done with some stored proc or function, no C# should be required.

Answer (score 1):

***One thing you can do :***

In ***`SQL Server Agent`***, create a job which calls a `batch` file. Configure the batch file which calls the rest service.

Comment: And then what!? How would you call the rest service from the batch file ?

Comment: Configured Job will execute and it will run the batch file. The written service will also get executed